# How to add UIImageView above UINavigationController's bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have UITableView based on UINavigationController. After clicking on any row application switch to another view which have UINavigationController too. In new view I want to add UIImageView above UINavigationController's bar but not cover it. How can I do this?

Comment: "Above the bar, but don't cover it"?  You know that's an oxymoron right?

Comment: What do you mean by above? Positioned vertically higher on the screen, or layered on top of the navigation bar? If the latter then ditto CodaFi, unless you want it to be transparent, in which case saying so would clear up a lot of confusion and ambiguity in your question.

Comment: @MartinH Yes, positioned vertically higher on the screen. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find easer solution. Just need to set needed frame's coordinates of self.navigationController.navigationBar: 
`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMakeCoordinates];`

Comment: its didn't worked for me :(, any suggestions? I have navigation bar inside UITabBarController.

Answer (score 2):

(based on your comment) this is what I'd do to place the image "above" in terms of y co-ordinate, and not in terms of subviews.

In the new view,

hide the navigationController's navigationBar 
[navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

Add a UIToolbar, with an origin of your interest and size of (320, 44), assuming that you are doing this on iPhone, with the image vertically above the bar.

Remember to un-hide the navigation bar, if you go to your old/previous view which had no image above the navigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

Add your UIImageView as a subview of self.navigationController.view and supply coordinates close to or less than zero to position it higher than the UINavigationBar.